# Laravel 5.2 : delete() And forceDelete()

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

In My Controller :

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $task = Task::findOrFail($id);
    if($task->forceDeleting){
      $task->forceDelete();
    }
    else {
      $task->delete();
    }
      return back();
}
```

In the above method the `else` section is working but the `if` is not working and throws error `No query results for model [App\Task]` with `URI` shows `http://localhost/Final/public/todo/28`

I am using the same method from views to `softDeletes` and `Permanent Deletes`.

```
{{ Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE', 'route' => ['todo.destroy', $task->id]]) }}
{{ Form::button('<i aria-hidden="true"></i>', array('type' => 'submit', 'class' => 'fa fa fa-trash fa-3x complete-icon')) }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Comment: this is not a solution but try to dd the if condition and see if it gives the proper result then the same to the forcedelete() , just to help locate the probleme

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems there's no task with id=28. But probably there's also another option. This task is already deleted (using soft deletes), so maybe you should change:

```
$task = Task::findOrFail($id);
```

into

```
$task = Task::withTrashed()->findOrFail($id);
```

**EDIT**

In case you want to delete (completely) model that is soft deleted you should use the following code (you should use `trashed()` method):

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $task = Task::withTrashed()->findOrFail($id);
    if(!$task->trashed()){
      $task->delete();
    }
    else {
      $task->forceDelete();
    }
    return back();
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate for the answer, With your method, Soft delete is working but force isn't working.

Comment: @Shafee And what exactly `forceDeleting` should do? When do you want to force delete model?

Comment: I am answering my question, Please comment then.

Comment: Yep ! Thank You Sir :)

Answer (score 2):

The `if($task->deleted_at == null)` done the magic.

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $task = Task::withTrashed()->findOrFail($id);
    if($task->deleted_at == null){
      $task->delete();
    }
    else {
      $task->forceDelete();
    }
    return back();
}
```

Comment: Yeah, That was a mistake, I have fixed that.